# Converting audio files on webserver

Tags: php, audio, hosting

I am looking to start a website which will need to convert any audio file to a low quality wav pcm file. So far I have found the possibilities to use ffmpeg or an external converter (like www.online-convert.com). Both of them have their drawbacks:

- ffmpeg is not supported by most hosting companies, due to the cpu load (although it would be minimal probably in this case). I am not looking for a dedicated server, since I want to keep the cost for hosting as low as possible.
- dependency on an external party is not optimal.

My question to you people is whether you see any other possibilities to solve this issue (preferably within a PHP environment). Thanks!

Comment: Hardly. ffmpeg is the de facto standard. Whatever library you're going to use, it's going to be CPU intensive. Get a host that supports ffmpeg or get your own dedicated (virtual) server. If you're halfway serious about the project, that should really not be the limiting factor. Servers are cheap these days.

Comment: VPS are not that much more expensive than web hosts.. if your loads will be low a small instance (very cheap ) will solve your problem for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way you could accomplish this on a (correctly configured) [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) hosting service alone. You need to either control external programs (like your [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) example) or send the file somewhere else and get it back converted.

So you should try looking for something different, either a full linux system (dedicated server, virtual server, chroot, whatever) or some LAMP hosting with access to external commands and/or dedicated file conversion services.

Comment: "No way" is a bit strong. It's perfectly possible to write a PHP program that converts files to WAV. It won't be fast, it's a lot of work to write and it's the worst option, but it is *an* option.

Comment: Thanks people! Not going to write it in PHP, so will start looking for a VPS!

Comment: @deceze memory and execution time limits on PHP scripts (I'm assuming both are part of a "correctly configured LAMP service") *will* pose a limit on the amount of data you are able to process, and the question asks for conversion of "any audio file". So no, a standard LAMP hosting is *not* an option because even if you code it and code it well, it would be able to convert only samples shorter than some given maximum length.